# jd eclipseでブレークポイントが使えない

Tags: java, eclipse

JD-Eclipseをプラグインとして追加した後、classファイルにブレークポイントをセットすると以下のメッセージが表示されてプログラムが中断されません。
classファイル内にセットしたブレークポイントを機能させる方法を教えてください。

Unable to install breakpoint in xxxApp due to missing line number attributes. Modify compiler options to generate line number attributes.

Reason:
Absent Line Number Information

Comment: 回答になるかわからないのでコメントでお返ししますが、プラグインインストール後はeclipse cleanをして、コンパイル済みクラスを一度キレイに消してからでないと、うまく動作しなかったと記憶しております。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージをそのまま解釈すると、該当クラスにデバッグ情報(行番号)が付与されていません。これはデフォルトでは付与される情報です。
(`javac`オプションに`-g:none`を指定することでデバッグ情報を付与しないことも可能です。`javac`オプションの詳細は[こちら](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/6/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)を参照してください。)

この行番号情報が付与されている場合、jd-eclipseでclassファイルを開くとコメントで行番号が挿入されるようですので、確認は容易でしょう。

[image: jd-eclipse]
[確認環境: Eclipse4.5.1 Mac OS X (Cocoa) 64-bit / JD-Eclipse1.0.0-RC2]

行番号が無いのであればデバッグ情報付きで再コンパイルし、それを用いる必要があります。
行番号があるにも関わらず停止できないのであれば他の原因ということになります(が、現在の質問文だけでは情報が不足しています)。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ブレークポイントを機能させるには行番号情報が必要ということですね。
コンパイル時のオプションが原因だったとは気づきませんでした。